# Both if and else are executing Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

The 2nd if statement works nicely but the first one always executes with the else statement and never lonely

this entire jquery function is inside another function that is called inside
the "$(document).ready" command

just used to console.log() to find out where is the problem but unfortunately have no idea about it

```
$("#pager").on("click", "li", function () {

    if ($(this)[0] == $("#pager > li:first-child")[0]) {
        console.log("first")
        selected--;
    }

    if ($(this)[0] == $("#pager > li:last-child")[0]) {
        console.log("last")
        selected++;
    }

    else {
        console.log("numbers")
        selected = $(this).html();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `if` should be an `else if` that is why.

```js
$("#pager").on("click", "li", function () {

    if ($(this)[0] == $("#pager > li:first-child")[0]) {
        console.log("first")
        //selected--;
    }

    else if ($(this)[0] == $("#pager > li:last-child")[0]) {
        console.log("last")
        //selected++;
    }

    else {
        console.log("numbers")
        //selected = $(this).html();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id=pager><li>test</li></ul>
```